# How do I change the default location of the log files for GAE's bulkloader?

Tags: google-app-engine

While working on my GAE project under my dev environment, whenever I upload data to my dev datastore, the logfiles are stored in my current directory, for instance:

```
C:\dev\ls
bulkloader-log-20090912.104643
bulkloader-log-20090912.104648
bulkloader-log-20090912.104731
bulkloader-log-20090912.105526
bulkloader-log-20090912.110428
bulkloader-progress-20090912.104648.sql3
bulkloader-progress-20090912.104731.sql3
bulkloader-progress-20090912.105526.sql3
bulkloader-progress-20090912.110428.sql3
project
```

`project` is my GAE app.  The above is generated when I run the command `appcfg.py upload_data`.  Is there a way to tell GAE where to store those log files, for instance in a log folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--log_file=...` option to `appcfg.py`, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html): with this command line option you can give the complete path to the log file, including folder and name. (You cannot give JUST the folder and let it figure out the name; for that, you need to write a tiny script that figures out the name then calls `appcfg.py`).